# SIGINT received from children processes too

Tags: c, unix, signals, signal-handling

I have 2 programs (written by me). The first one called "MAN" will invoke "D" (the second one) which is a process that will run in background until terminated in some ways.

I would like to terminate MAN without terminating D.

I try to terminate MAN using ctrl + c and it terminates man correctly (I intercepted the sigint signal), now I want that D keeps running, however when MAN receives CTRL + C, D receive it too.

How to handle this situation? It's important that I would like to keep the possibility to run only D and terminate with CTRL + C. The problem comes when I run it through MAN, I don't want to terminate it with CTRL + C which should reach MAN only.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think the correct way would be to disconnect the D process from the console, that's called a daemon.

Comment: I were thinking about something like this, but I didn't know it was possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child process (D) should disassociate from the controlling terminal by calling `setsid(2)`.